# JWT sha256 hashes don't match the Internet draft examples

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, jwt

I've been working on getting JWT working in Google Apps Scripts. Since I was getting bad results I went to the JWS Internet-Draft at:
http://self-issued.info/docs/draft-ietf-jose-json-web-signature.html#HS256Encoding

Using this example object:
{"iss":"joe",
   "exp":1300819380,
   "http://example.com/is_root":true}

Snippet of code:

```
var eClaim = UTF8.encode(JSON.stringify(claim));
eClaim = Base64EncodeUrl(eClaim);
```

my Base64url is:

```
eyJpc3MiOiJqb2UiL----CJleHAiOjEzMDA4MTkzODAs----Imh0dHA6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9pc19yb290Ijp0cnVlfQ
```

(- added by me)

What the Specs say I should get:

```
eyJpc3MiOiJqb2UiLA0KICJleHAiOjEzMDA4MTkzODAsDQogImh0dHA6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS9pc19yb290Ijp0cnVlfQ
```

There are gaps in my encoded object(again I added ---- to show the gaps). I though it may be a \n,\r or \t but none of that matched the expected outcome.  I did paste the example into an online base64url encoder/decoder. My base64 decoded perfectly and the example JSON encoded exactly like mine.  Am I doing something wrong or could the internet-draft incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you tried \r and \n , but that's what I determined it to be after decodeing 
your samples.

the difference is the line break CRLF in the example version

theirs:

```
0000000  7b  22  69  73  73  22  3a  22  6a  6f  65  22  2c  0d  0a  20
          {   "   i   s   s   "   :   "   j   o   e   "   ,  cr  nl  sp
0000020  22  65  78  70  22  3a  31  33  30  30  38  31  39  33  38  30
          "   e   x   p   "   :   1   3   0   0   8   1   9   3   8   0
0000040  2c  0d  0a  20  22  68  74  74  70  3a  2f  2f  65  78  61  6d
          ,  cr  nl  sp   "   h   t   t   p   :   /   /   e   x   a   m
0000060  70  6c  65  2e  63  6f  6d  2f  69  73  5f  72  6f  6f  74  22
          p   l   e   .   c   o   m   /   i   s   _   r   o   o   t   "
0000100  3a  74  72  75  65  7d
          :   t   r   u   e   }
0000106
```

yours:

```
0000000  7b  22  69  73  73  22  3a  22  6a  6f  65  22  2c  22  65  78
          {   "   i   s   s   "   :   "   j   o   e   "   ,   "   e   x
0000020  70  22  3a  31  33  30  30  38  31  39  33  38  30  2c  22  68
          p   "   :   1   3   0   0   8   1   9   3   8   0   ,   "   h
0000040  74  74  70  3a  2f  2f  65  78  61  6d  70  6c  65  2e  63  6f
          t   t   p   :   /   /   e   x   a   m   p   l   e   .   c   o
0000060  6d  2f  69  73  5f  72  6f  6f  74  22  3a  74  72  75  65  7d
          m   /   i   s   _   r   o   o   t   "   :   t   r   u   e   }
0000100
```

As I understand it JSON does not require line breaks after the separator commas.

Comment: You are right, all examples in the specification contain linebreaks. These examples are not incorrect at all.